# ImageMagick PHP need a good quality thumbnail generation

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am using php imagemagick to generate thumbnail image.

- If i give bestfit true and size is 50x50 it generating 36x50 size image(good quality)
- if i give bestfit false and size is 50x50 it generating 50x50 size image(bad quality)

I need a solution that whatever the image size(minimum i will upload 200X200) i give
it need to give 50x50 with good quality and techniques there in ImageMAgick ??

Comment: Please show some code and, ideally, examples

Comment: Does "good quality" mean "maintain proportions"? E.g., if you upload 300x200 image, you want it to be resized to 75x50 and then cropped to 50x50 (by removing 13px from left and 12px from right in this case)?

Comment: $originalImage = tmp image uploaded
newImage = $this->rootpath.'/'.$location_1.'/'.$thumb['name'].$name;
     //Passing the imagepath and width&height need to generat thumb        
      $this->makeThumb($originalImage,$newImage,50,50,true)
    // In the above last parameter is bestfit(true/false)

Comment: function makeThumb($originalImage,$newImage,$width,$height,$bestfit)
{
$width  = intval($width);
$height = intval($height);
$im = new Imagick();
try{
/* Read the image file */
  $im->readImage($originalImage); 
 /* Thumbnail the image ( width 100, preserve dimensions ) */
$im->thumbnailImage($width,$height,$bestfit);
/* Write the thumbail to disk */
  $im->writeImage($newImage);
/* Get the size of uploaded image */
 $size = getimagesize($newImage);
/* Get the current height and widht  difference*/   
}
catch (ImagickException $e) {
return false;
}
return true;
$im->destroy();
}

Comment: * If i upload 300x200 .. It need to find the center point of that image and need to calculate 50x50 from there..
    that need to remove left and right some px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [PHP Thumb](http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/) (MIT license).

It supports **Adaptive Resizing**.

What it does is resize the image to get as close as possible to the desired dimensions, then crops the image down to the proper size from the center.

```
require_once '/path/to/ThumbLib.inc.php';  

$thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create('test.jpg');  
$thumb->adaptiveResize(50, 50)->save('/path/to/new_thumb.jpg');
```

> PHP Thumb is a light-weight image
>   manipulation library aimed at
>   thumbnail generation. It features the
>   ability to resize by width, height,
>   and percentage, create custom crops,
>   or square crops from the center, and
>   rotate the image.

[PHP Thumb Github WIKI](https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb/wiki)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`$im->cropThumbnailImage()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-cropthumbnailimage.php) instead of `$im->thumbnailImage()`.